# fopen() stream to popen() for progress bar/controll - but how to get stdout of popen()?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to write simple c function which would give me possibility to see progress of data transfer from one stream to other stream and display it on my char LCD.

I manage to transfer the data and indicate the progress but how to get result of the piping?

So basically i want to do in c corresponds to shell command:

```
/home/image.img | md5sum > result
```

The problem i have i with the stdout. I would like to get it to a char * result.

In other words the md5sum returns a string on the screen like this "5193fd9ebfa30bcb914e7af4760deb15" but i would like to get it to my char * result for further usage in the function.

```
FILE *in_stream, *out_stream;
#define TRANSFER_BLOCK_SIZE 1048576 //one MB
int n=0;
int i=0;
long int input_size=0; 
unsigned char buffer[TRANSFER_BLOCK_SIZE];

if((out_stream=popen("md5sum","w"))==NULL)
   {
   perror(output_pipe_name);
   return 1;
   }
if((in_stream=fopen("/home/gregorek/image.img","r"))==NULL)
   {
   perror(input_file_name);
   return 1;    
   }
//check total size of the input file
fseek(in_stream,0,SEEK_END);
input_size=(ftell(in_stream)/TRANSFER_BLOCK_SIZE)+1;
fseek(in_stream,0,SEEK_SET);
//
do
    {
    i++;
    memset(buffer,'\0',TRANSFER_BLOCK_SIZE);
    n=fread(buffer,sizeof(unsigned char),TRANSFER_BLOCK_SIZE,in_stream);
    lcd_display(i); //this is my progress indicator
    fwrite(buffer,sizeof(unsigned char),n,out_stream);
    }
while(!feof(in_stream));

fclose(in_stream);
pclose(out_stream);
```

return 0;
}

thanks

Comment: What kind of command is this `/home/image.img | md5sum > result`? `image.img` is an executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`popen` doesn't really give you what you want here, as it's a specialized library function. Use the system calls `fork` and `pipe` directly instead.

You use `fork` to create a child process and `pipe` to redirect `stdout` back to the parent process.

See [this](http://jineshkj.wordpress.com/2006/12/22/how-to-capture-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-of-child-program/) example for details.

This is incidentally exactly what the shell does when you command it to do this:

```
cat /home/image.img | md5sum > result
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with fork and pipe so far so please correct me if i'm wrong: My progress bar function should run completely in child process.The parent process should listen via the open pipe what is redirected from child's stdout to the pipe?

Comment: Exactly how you organize it is up to you, but you should know that pipes are unidirectional, so you need to take care from what end you read and to what end you write.

Comment: Good to hear! As an aside, I don't know if this is for practical use or just to teach yourself some C, but this is a task that would be much easier to implement in for instance Python.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Henrik,
Here is the code for all of you who wonder how to do it:

```
int     fd_pipe[2], nbytes, status;
char    pipe_buffer[1000];
memset(pipe_buffer,'\0',1000);

        if(pipe(fd_pipe)!=0)
            {
            perror("fd_pipe:");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) 
            {
            perror("Fork failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        else
            {
            if(pid>0) //The parent's part
                {
                // Parent process closes output side of the pipe 
                close(fd_pipe[1]);
                //Parent wait's untill the child is done
                wait(&status);
                // Read in a string from the pipe's input side 
                nbytes = read(fd_pipe[0], pipe_buffer, sizeof(pipe_buffer)); 

                printf("Received %d chars, string: %s \n", nbytes, pipe_buffer);
                                    //on the end close the other side of pipe                   
                                    close(fd_pipe[0]);
                }
            else
                {   // The child's part
                /* Child process closes input side of the pipe */
                close(fd_pipe[0]);
                //redirect the stdout(1) to the fd_pipe and then close the sdtout
                dup2(fd_pipe[1],1); 
                //Do the thing which creates the result message 
                system("/image/"IMAGE_NAME | md5sum");

                //on the end close the other side of pipe 
                close(fd_pipe[1]); 
                exit(0);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Well done, but this only works in this (and similiar) use case: if the client writes too much, it will block, `wait()` will never return and the whole stuff is locked up. But for the few output bytes of `md5sum`, it is ok, thus +1.

Comment: Side node: you could do `close(fd_pipe[1]);` as early as directly after the `dup2(fd_pipe[1],1);`, as the called program will have it then and all will be fine. Maybe it would be even cleaner to `close(1);` after the `system()` call, but I'm not sure.